# Push Notifications getting dropped in iOS randomly

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I am working on an iOS application built using React-Native and used OneSignal for PushNotifications. Recently I upgraded to react-native version `0.61.5` and a compatible version of OneSignal SDK (`v3.6.4`) along with that.

However, more often than not notifications get dropped somewhere in the middle and not reach mobile app. Here is what I know:

1. Devices are properly registered on OneSignal and I can see it in the
   `Audience` tab after I register.
2. Status of notifications is `delivered` in OneSignal. That is, it has been successfully sent to APNs servers.
3. Sometimes notifications do get received. So, the problem with mobile app code also seems unlikely.

Here is a scenario that I tried:

I uninstalled the app and installed the latest version at around 11.40 AM today. Logged in my account, set time for notification to be 12:00 PM (there is a setting in the app to set the time to receive notifications). Then I closed the app by swiping it out of app list by the double pressing home screen. But did not receive a notification at 12:00 PM. OneSignal showed delivered.

Then I opened the app again, used it for some time and set time for 2:00 PM again. This time I received the notification.

I am not really sure where can the problem be.